# How to color a grayscale image based on a mask?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pydicom

I have two images: A grayscale image, and a binary mask with the same dimensions. How do I color the image on the mask, while the rest of the image remains grayscale?

Here's and example:

[image]

Comment: Convert your `gray` image to 3-channel color image. Now for every white (255) pixel in the mask, assign the color (255, 255, 0): `gray[mask==255]=(255, 255, 0)`

Comment: How do I convert my gray image to a 3-channel color image? I'm using pydicom.dcmread.pixel_array, which reads the image as a 2D numpy array

Comment: `gray = cv2.merge((gray, gray, gray))` express the pixel intensities of original gray image across three channels

Comment: Another way is `gray = cv2.cvtColor(grey, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`. Note that it doesn't matter which method you use when you're converting from gray to RGB but it does matter when converting RGB to gray. [link to doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_gray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressing your grey image pixel values across 3-channels gives you a color image. The result would look the same but when you check the dimensions it would be 3.

```
gray_3_channel = cv2.merge((gray, gray, gray))

gray.shape
>>> (158, 99)
gray_3_channel.shape
>>> (158, 99, 3)
```

For every white (255) pixel in the mask, assign the color (255, 255, 0) in `gray_3_channel`:

```
gray_3_channel[mask==255]=(255, 255, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers. Would I have to normalise the pixels of the gray image before? As they go up to 65535 atm.

Also, which function would you use to show the image? As it's a mix of grayscale and color, so plt.imshow(img_array, cmap="gray") is probably not valid

Comment: @FrederikFaarup To show a color image avoid `cmap` just use `plt.imshow(img_array)`

Comment: Also if you want to restrict the pixel values to unsigned 8-bit integer (0 - 255) you can normalize

Comment: Cheers. As an addition, how do I make the overlay transparent, for example 0.5 opacity? I have another heatmap (np array of probabilities), which I want to overlay an image

Comment: @FrederikFaarup You can search for `cv2.addWeighted()` function

Comment: Ah nice! I couldn't get it to work, so I create the overlay (like you've showed), and then cv2.addWeighted() the original image with the image with overlay. It works :-))